# Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Fails

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I have a WPF UI called GUI.xaml and i need to change labels and images from other class. More over i need to perform a long task, so i'm using a background worker. So i've read a solution in this site:

In GUI.xaml.cs:

```
public static ChangeGUI someClass;    
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        someClass = new ChangeGUI(this); //          
        TaskClass.ConnectionThread(SuperHero.getUserID());
    }
```

in ChangeGUI.cs:

```
public class ChangeGUI
{
    GUI _GUIRef;

    public ChangeGUI(GUI gui)
    {
        _GUIRef = gui;
    }

    public void ChangeLabel()
    {
        //here we can play with labels
    }
    public void ChangeMap(ImageSource tmp)
    {
        if (_GUIRef.image1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            _GUIRef.image1.Source = tmp;//ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
        else
            _GUIRef.image1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Changer(ChangeMap), tmp);
    }
}
```

Here i receive an error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
Help is welcome, 
Thank You!

Comment: I've Visual Studio in Italian. I try to translate in english: Language:System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: How and where are you creating `image1`? Can you also post the code from where `ChangeMap` is called? It seems to me like you're calling it from the worker, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: image1 is created in GUI.xaml: <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="3.04" Height="237" x:Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="318" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

Comment: ChangeMap is called by a function called by TaskClass.ConnectionThread() (so it is in the worker). How i can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created the `ImageSource` on the background thread, make sure you freeze it so that it's accessible from any thread:

```
var imageSource = ...;
imageSource.Freeze();
```